# New Array from Index Range Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

How can I do something like this? Take the first n elements from an array:

```
newNumbers = numbers[0..n]
```

Currently getting the following error:

```
error: could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

EDIT:

Here is the function that I'm working in.

```
func aFunction(numbers: Array<Int>, position: Int) -> Array<Int> {
    var newNumbers = numbers[0...position]
    return newNumbers
}
```

Answer (score 225, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var test = [1, 2, 3]
var n = 2
var test2 = test[0..<n]
```

Your issue could be with how you're declaring your array to begin with.

EDIT:

To fix your function, you have to cast your `Slice` to an array:

```
func aFunction(numbers: Array<Int>, position: Int) -> Array<Int> {
    var newNumbers = Array(numbers[0..<position])
    return newNumbers
}

// test
aFunction([1, 2, 3], 2) // returns [1, 2]
```

Comment: I've add a little more context to my question, I'm working inside a function. This works independently, but not inside the function.

Comment: Lovely! Cheers - that works. I'll accept the answer when it lets me.

Comment: Pedantic point, but this isn't really *casting* the `Slice` to an `Array`, but rather creating a new array from a slice. A cast would use the `as` operator: `numbers as Array` which would result in an error.

Comment: The language has changed, it uses three ellipsis and not two https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html

Comment: The two dots`..` changed to `..<`; the three dots (an ellipsis) have stayed the same. Thanks for the reminder, though; I updated the answer.

Comment: `...` is to including end index, `..<` to not including end index

Answer (score 151):

### #1. Using `Array` subscript with range

With Swift 5, when you write…

```
let newNumbers = numbers[0...position]
```

… `newNumbers` is not of type `Array<Int>` but is of type `ArraySlice<Int>`. That's because `Array`'s [`subscript(_:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2944258-subscript) returns an `ArraySlice<Element>` that, according to Apple, presents a view onto the storage of some larger array.

Besides, Swift also provides `Array` an initializer called [`init(_:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2907560-init) that allows us to create a new array from a `sequence` (including `ArraySlice`).

Therefore, you can use `subscript(_:​)` with `init(_:​)` in order to get a new array from the first *n* elements of an array:

```
let array = Array(10...14) // [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
let arraySlice = array[0..<3] // using Range
//let arraySlice = array[0...2] // using ClosedRange also works
//let arraySlice = array[..<3] // using PartialRangeUpTo also works
//let arraySlice = array[...2] // using PartialRangeThrough also works
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints [10, 11, 12]
```

---

### #2. Using `Array`'s `prefix(_:)` method

Swift provides a [`prefix(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689487-prefix) method for types that conform to `Collection` protocol (including `Array`). `prefix(_:)` has the following declaration:

```
func prefix(_ maxLength: Int) -> ArraySlice<Element>
```

> Returns a subsequence, up to maxLength in length, containing the initial elements.

Apple also states:

> If the maximum length exceeds the number of elements in the collection, the result contains all the elements in the collection.

Therefore, as an alternative to the previous example, you can use the following code in order to create a new array from the first elements of another array:

```
let array = Array(10...14) // [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
let arraySlice = array.prefix(3)
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints [10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, `Array` also has a `suffix` method that works like the `prefix` method shown here.

Answer (score 14):

## subscript

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
  public subscript(safe bounds: Range<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Element> {
    if bounds.lowerBound > count { return [] }
    let lower = Swift.max(0, bounds.lowerBound)
    let upper = Swift.max(0, Swift.min(count, bounds.upperBound))
    return self[lower..<upper]
  }
  
  public subscript(safe lower: Int?, _ upper: Int?) -> ArraySlice<Element> {
    let lower = lower ?? 0
    let upper = upper ?? count
    if lower > upper { return [] }
    return self[safe: lower..<upper]
  }
}
```

returns a copy of this range clamped to the given limiting range.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3]
    
arr[safe: 0..<1]    // returns [1]  assert(arr[safe: 0..<1] == [1])
arr[safe: 2..<100]  // returns [3]  assert(arr[safe: 2..<100] == [3])
arr[safe: -100..<0] // returns []   assert(arr[safe: -100..<0] == [])

arr[safe: 0, 1]     // returns [1]  assert(arr[safe: 0, 1] == [1])
arr[safe: 2, 100]   // returns [3]  assert(arr[safe: 2, 100] == [3])
arr[safe: -100, 0]  // returns []   assert(arr[safe: -100, 0] == [])
```

Comment: please add some description to the answer as well.

Comment: Very nice answer. What it essentially does is that it casts an ArraySlice<T> to an Array. Personally I wouldn't include as many asserts. As I usually want slice to fail if I provide false ranges etc.

Comment: The `Equatable` is not needed here...

Answer (score 3):

Array functional way:

```
   array.enumerated().filter { $0.offset < limit }.map { $0.element }
```

ranged:

```
 array.enumerated().filter { $0.offset >= minLimit && $0.offset < maxLimit }.map { $0.element }
```

The advantage of this method is such implementation is safe.

Answer (score 0):

One more variant using `extension` and argument name `range`

This extension uses `Range` and `ClosedRange`

```
extension Array {

    subscript (range r: Range<Int>) -> Array {
        return Array(self[r])
    }


    subscript (range r: ClosedRange<Int>) -> Array {
        return Array(self[r])
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
func testArraySubscriptRange() {
    //given
    let arr = ["1", "2", "3"]

    //when
    let result = arr[range: 1..<arr.count] as Array

    //then
    XCTAssertEqual(["2", "3"], result)
}

func testArraySubscriptClosedRange() {
    //given
    let arr = ["1", "2", "3"]

    //when
    let result = arr[range: 1...arr.count - 1] as Array

    //then
    XCTAssertEqual(["2", "3"], result)
}
```