# Trying to make a specific index in my array to no longer be of array type

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, reduce

I have an array that takes in a set of values. At a certain index in the array, the value is an array. So it looks like this

```
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
```

I'm trying to change the array value to be like this

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How would you go back about doing this in Swift?

Here is how I get the result

```
let array = [value1, value2, [value3, value4]].compactMap{$0}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what where the results? Show any code you have tried and what part you are having an issues with. [SO new-array-from-index-range-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034398/new-array-from-index-range-swift)

Comment: This solved my question, sorry for posting duplicate post

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward solution that handles int values and arrays of ints in the original array

```
let arr:[Any] = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]

var output: [Int] = []

for x in arr {
    if let value = x as? Int {
        output.append(value)
    } else if let array = x as? [Int] {
        output.append(contentsOf: array)
    }
    //else ignore
}
```