# Swift: Java equivalent of Arrays.copyOfRange for [UInt8]

Tags: swift

I am translating a java code to swift, and I want to know what is the equivalent for swift of Arrays.copyOfRange:

```
public static byte[] copyOfRange(byte[] original, int from, int to)
```

for my example I want to translate the next line:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(packet.value(), 2, packet.length())
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't add the answer to your question. You can post your solution as an answer, or accept one of the existing answers.

Comment: Ok edited......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java's `copyOfRange` will also pad the resulting array with zeroes if the upper range value is greater than the array length.  This function handles that case as well.

This function can be made generic.  It works for any type that conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` which is needed for the `0` padding.

```
func copyOfRange<T>(arr: [T], from: Int, to: Int) -> [T]? where T: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    guard from >= 0 && from <= arr.count && from <= to else { return nil }

    var to = to
    var padding = 0

    if to > arr.count {
        padding = to - arr.count
        to = arr.count
    }

    return Array(arr[from..<to]) + [T](repeating: 0, count: padding)
}
```

---

**Examples:**

```
let arr: [UInt8] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

if let result = copyOfRange(arr: arr, from: 0, to: 3) {
    print(result)  // [0, 1, 2]
}
if let result = copyOfRange(arr: arr, from: 7, to: 12) {
    print(result)  // [7, 8, 9, 0, 0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
func getRange (arr:[Int],from:Int,to:Int) -> [Int]? {

  if from >= 0 && from < arr.count && to >= 0 && to < arr.count && from < to {

     return Array(arr[from...to])
  }

 return nil
}
```

May write

```
extension Array  {

    func getRenage (from:Int,to:Int) -> [Element]? {

        if from >= 0 && from < self.count && to >= 0 && to < self.count && from < to {

            return Array(self[from...to])
        }

        return nil
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you check your code before posting? This does not compile.

Comment: I was just about to press "Post Your Answer" when I saw yours come up. Mine was essentially the same. The key part to this answer is the range subscript `arr[from...to]` which is essentially doing the equivalent of `copyOfRange`. (Except that in Swift you can also use this syntax to write to a subset of the array as well as to extract it.)

Comment: @MartinR  hand write it

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I want to give it a byteArray so I just have to replace Int by UInt8?

Comment: @MickaelBelhassen yeah

Comment: There is a pretty good discussion of the details of this syntax at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034398/new-array-from-index-range-swift

Comment: You want `from <= to`.  Also, no need to then check `from < arr.count`.

Comment: @vacawama the op can customize it for his needs , he should be aware of all possible cases according to his use case

Comment: Since you need `0 <= from <= to < arr.count`, you only need to check 3 conditions `from >= 0 && to >= from && to < arr.count`.

Comment: Look at my edit, and change your answer and I could put the subject resolved

Answer (score 0):

This should definitfly work:

```
    var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    var partOfArray = array[5...8]
    print(partOfArray)
```

Comment: This answer could be much more helpful if you explain why it is correct ad relate it to the specifics of the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

```
    func getRange(arr: [UInt8], from: Int, to: Int) -> [UInt8]? {

    if from >= 0 && to >= from && to <= arr.count{

        return Array(arr[from..<to])
    }

    return nil
}
```