# Get new array of values from within sorted array

Tags: swift

I have an array of SCNNode that are sorted by their y positions(Float):

```
nodesSortedByY = scene.rootNode.childNodes.sorted { $0.position.y > $1.position.y }
```

What I would like to do is get a new array from `nodesSortedByY` where the y values are within a certain range in a similar way to how [subscript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34300872/6734301) works but by passing actual values not indexes.

For example:

```
let nodesSortedByY = [5.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0]
let subRange = nodesSortedByY(4.0...2.0)
print(subRange) // [4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0]
```

I tried using indexes originally combined with [this binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61309651/6734301) but it doesnt work if the values dont exist within the array:

```
let yPositions = nodesSortedByY.map({ $0.position.y })
let firstIndex = yPositions.binarySearch(forFirstIndexOf: firstValue) ?? 0
let lastIndex = yPositions.binarySearch(forLastIndexOf: lastValue) ?? 0
nodesSortedByY[lastIndex...firstIndex]
```

Comment: Are you looking for `filter()`?  `let filtered = nodesSortedByY.filter({ (2.0...4.0).contains($0) })`

Comment: Not quite, it would have to be filtered by a range of the nodes y positions somehow?

Comment: DIdn't you want to get all the values of "y" if they are between 2.0 and 4.0? That's what's doing the filter. Else, keeping your last idea: `let lowerBound = nodesSortedByY.firstIndex(where: { $0 <= 4.0 })
let upperBound = nodesSortedByY.lastIndex(where: { $0 >= 2.0 })
let sub = nodesSortedByY[lowerBound!...upperBound!]`

Comment: i want an array of SCNNode still but sorting it by `y` and getting the the new range array by the nodes y values

Comment: I guess so, but the author used `map`, and simplified his example to `[Double]`, but my solutions should work.

Comment: A hack would be to modify the first suggestion somewhat to filter in the sorted order, `nodesSortedByY.filter { (-4.0 ... -2.0).contains(-$0)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to `filter()`.

```
let sub = nodesSortedByY.filter { (2.0...4.0).contains($0.position.y) }
```

We keep only the elements in `nodesSortedByY` where its `y` position is inside the range [2.0; 4.0].

Since you sorted your array (descending order), you can applied that logic too (modification of your attempt)

```
let lowerBound = nodesSortedByY.firstIndex(where: { $0 <= 4.0 }) ?? nodesSortedByY.startIndex
let upperBound = nodesSortedByY.lastIndex(where: { $0 >= 2.0 }) ?? nodesSortedByY.endIndex
let sub = nodesSortedByY[lowerBound...upperBound]
```

Comment: `let sub = nodesSortedByY.filter { (2.0...4.0).contains($0.position.y) }` works perfectly for me thank you, i didnt realize you could filter like that

Comment: @Wazza  `2.0...4.0 ~= $0.position.y`